# HUBL HUBSPOT - Articles description not showing in block posts

Tags: hubspot

I have a problem with the visibility of description of ARTICLES in block's post, they are showing other content but not the first paragraph of the article, as it supposed to do.

[print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJnYD.jpg)

here is the code (just the part of the BLOG)

```
 <div class="lp-section blog-section"> 
  <h2>
    Blog
  </h2>
  <ul>
    {% set rec_posts = blog_recent_posts("default", 3) %}
    {% for rec_post in rec_posts %}
    <li>
      <div class="lp-block">
        {% if rec_post.featured_image %}
        
        <a class="resource__post-image" 
           alt="{{ rec_post.featured_image_alt_text }}"
           style="background-image: url('{{ rec_post.featured_image }}');" 
           href="{{ rec_post.absolute_url }}">
        </a>

        {% endif %}
        {% set featured_tag = rec_post.topic_list | first %}
        {% if featured_tag %}
        <div class="content content-description">
          <div>
            <span class="keyword">{{ featured_tag }}</span>
            {% endif %}
            <h3><a href="{{ rec_post.absolute_url }}">{{ rec_post.name }}</a></h3>
            <p class="description">{{ content.meta_description | default(content.post_summary, true) | truncatehtml(150, '...', false) }}</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <a class="ghost-cta" href="{{ rec_post.absolute_url }}">
              Read more
            </a>
          </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  <a class="link" href="https://ai.reportlinker.com/en/resources/blog">+ More articles </a>
</div>
```

Could somebody please help me please?

Answer (score 0):

change your line

```hubl
<p class="description">{{ content.meta_description | 
default(content.post_summary, true) | truncatehtml(150, '...', false) }}</p>
```

to

```hubl
<p class="description">{{ content.post_summary | truncatehtml(150, '...', false) }}</p>
```

Your original block of code is using the `content.meta_description` which is set on the blog post's settings.

The `content.post_summary` grabs the content before the blog post's `<!-- more -->` tag